# I want to dedicate one USB port to a VirtualBox OS

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, usb-storage

I am specifically creating a VirtualBox environment to deal with malware files. When I connect my USB pen-drive, I want it to be opened in the virtual environment, but the main environment i.e., Windows 7 should not be able to recognize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set up a [**USB Filter**](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/server-virtualization/using-usb-device-filters-with-sun-xvm-virtualbox/) for this.

[image]

Comment: It recognizes with the vendor name or the port number?

Comment: You can define your own settings based on device label string, serial no. and more. Please read the article.